# javascript weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, position

i have some code that tries to list images based on their height. the weird thing is that the same code kinda works when i try with 2 images but doesn't work when i try with 3 or more

site: http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z

if you click on a menu button, the images should list themselves one below the other filling a width as wide as that black line thingy. if you click the 1st button that creates 2 thumbnails they work but the other buttons dont do nothing

code: http://jsfiddle.net/5qt3s/

i have tried to remove all irrelevant stuff to keep it as simple as possible

what could i be doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have two small images on your webspace (euroscala.balkanium.com):

```
images/shkalla/small/1.jpg
images/shkalla/small/2.jpg
```

`images/shkalla/small/3.jpg` doesn't exist so when it gets to this image (in the loop inside `createThumbs`) instead of firing the `img.onload` event it fires `img.onerror`, because it fails to load the image. This means your `totalLoaded` count never reaches `totalThumbs` and `redrawThumbs` doesn't get called.

Either create the missing images, or hook into the `img.onerror` event and skip the image.

Comment: oh god how can i be such a moron :D

thanks so much i spent like half a day on this and would likely spend another week before i get it :(